# How to get Yahoo Authentication token in ASP.net 4

Tags: restful-authentication, yahoo-api

Here is link for Yahoo Authentication service... 
http://upcoming.yahoo.com/services/api/token_auth.php

I am confused how to do it in .net where to start by using .net authentication to get token then consume this token in this APIs

http://upcoming.yahoo.com/services/api/event.add.php